# Send list of file names on server

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to send a list of file names on the server to the client only exactly once. Now from reading questions on here I know how to get all file names from directory using the following:

```
if(d)
{
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        if(dir->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            if (sendto(sock, dir->d_name, sizeof(dir->d_name), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr)) != sizeof(dir->d_name))
            {
                printf("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(d);
}
```

From my understanding this will read only file names and send them to the client. However when I execute this code, my client keeps receiving the same file names until it crashes with a segmentation fault. To get around this I have tried this:

```
if(d)
{
    while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        if(dir->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            if(strcmp(dir_last, dir->d_name) != 0 || strlen(dir_last) == 1)
            {
                if (sendto(sock, dir->d_name, sizeof(dir->d_name), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, sizeof(clientAddr)) != sizeof(dir->d_name))
                {
                    printf("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
                }

                strcpy(dir_last, dir->d_name);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(d);
}
```

My think was:

If the `dir_last` (last file name sent) is set has a size of `1` (`'\0'`) or is equal to the last `dir_name` sent then break out of the loop otherwise send the name of the file. However, it just keeps loop and looping.

The file names I am trying to send are:

```
server.c
client.c
Makefile
```

The client code that received information from server:

```
    #define ECHOMAX 255     /* Longest string to echo */

    int sock;                        /* Socket descriptor */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Echo server address */
    unsigned int fromSize;           /* In-out of address size for recvfrom() */
    char echoString[1];              /* String to send to server */
    char echoBuffer[ECHOMAX+1];      /* Buffer for receiving echoed string */
    int echoStringLen;               /* Length of string to echo */

    /* Recv a response */
    fromSize = sizeof(fromAddr);
    if ((respStringLen = recvfrom(sock, echoBuffer, ECHOMAX, 0, 
         (struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromSize)) != ECHOMAX)
        printf("recvfrom() failed\n");

    if (echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr != fromAddr.sin_addr.s_addr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: received a packet from unknown source.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //ECHOBUFFER VALUE IS NOW FILENAME FROM SERVER 
    /* null-terminate the received data */
    printf("%i\n", respStringLen);
    echoBuffer[respStringLen] = '\0';
    printf("Received: %s\n", echoBuffer);    /* Print the echoed arg */
```

Comment: You should consider taking this opportunity to work on using a debugger.  The time you spend will pay off in this first instance and many dividends beyond.

Comment: `readdir()` will never return the same file twice. I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You say the client *crashes* and yet you look at the server first? My guess is the client code has pointer issues.

Comment: If the client code is what you use, you never initialize the socket `sock` before calling `recvfrom` ... crash is to be expected ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta That was implied